# Can we use addresses to query balances from EOSJS?

Tags: eosjs, balances, address

I wanted to know if we could use addresses instead of account names to query balances (get_currency_balance) from eosjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like addresses on EOS. Only Accountnames and key-pairs.

There's no endpoint for querying by public Key.

Key-pairs can be used for multiple Accounts - so you can't query the Balance of a single account by public Key.